# setting output of a command to a variable

Tags: bash, command-line

How can I put the output of `head -15 textfile.txt` to a variable `$X` to use it in an `if` command like this:

```
 if $X = 'disabled' then
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x="$(head -15 testfile.txt)"
if [ "$x" = disabled ]
then
    echo "We are disabled"
fi
```

Generally, any time that you want to capture the output from a command into a shell variable, use the form:  `variable="$(command args ...)"`.  The `variable=` part is assignment.  The `$(...)` part is command substitution.

Also note that the shell does not do `if` statements in the form `if $X = 'disabled'`.  The shell expects that a command follows the `if` and the shell will evaluate the return code of that command.  In the case above, I run the `test` command which can be written as either `test ...` or `[ ... ]`.

Many consider it best practices to use lower-case variables for shell scripts.  This is because system defined variables are upper case and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one.  On the other hand, there is no system variable called `X` so it is not a real problem here.