# How do I set a bash variable that contains another variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to set the variable service to be the value of

```
var1=first/second
echo $var1 | cut -d '/' -f 1
var2=$var1 | cut -d '/' -f 1"
echo $var2
```

The result of `echo $var1 | cut -d '/' -f 1` is "first" which is correct.  However, I haven't been able to set the result of this to another variable.  In the case above, var2 is empty.

What would the correct syntax for line 3 be so that the part of the string before the `\` is returned as the value of var2?

Comment: See also [Storing output of command in shell variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4569/80216), [Calculate variable and output it to another variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50215/80216), [Bash: Assign output of pipe to a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/338000/80216), [setting output of a command to a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122014/80216), and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use command substitution

```
var2=$(echo "$var1" | cut -d '/' -f 1)
```

However in this case it would be better to use the shell's parameter substitution directly:

```
$ var2=${var1%/*}
$ echo "$var2"
first
```

(removes the shortest trailing substring matching `/*`) and

```
$ var3=${var1#*/}
$ echo "$var3"
second
```

(removes the shortest leading substring matching `*/`) should you need it as well.